# Border & Padding not showing/working on .row-fluid class in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap for my first major product, I've merely played around with it in the past, now I have the following in my HTML view (this is indicative of the structure and is repeated, it's just an example to show how I have a `div.row-fluid` and 2 or 1 child divs)

```
<div id="menuWrapper" >
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-xs-9 menu-detail">
            Vorspeisen
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 selected-orange text-right">
            ab 2.80 €
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            Hausgemachter Griebenschmalz auf Schrotbrot
            <span class="grey-subtext">Portion mit Spreewald - Gurke</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 text-right">
            3.80 €
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            Hausgemachter Griebenschmalz auf Harzer Käze
            <span class="grey-subtext">Portion mit Spreewald - Gurke</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 text-right">
            3.80 €
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid menu-header">
        <div class="col-xs-9 menu-detail">
            Hauptspeisen
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 selected-orange text-right">
            ab 12.80 €
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            Ragu alla Bolognese
            <span class="grey-subtext">mit orginal Parmesan Käse</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 text-right">
            7.80 €
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            Fish & Chips
            <span class="grey-subtext">mit orginal Mushy-Erbse </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 text-right">
            10.80 €
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            Beriner Teller
            <span class="grey-subtext">Bulette mit Kartoffelsalat, hausgemachter Art mit Jogurt-Dressing und original Spreewalk-Gurke</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 text-right">
            9.80 €
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-xs-9 menu-detail">
            Dessert
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 selected-orange text-right">
            ab 2.90 €
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            Alt Deutscher Käsekuchen
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 text-right">
            ab 2.90 €
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                Alt Britisch Käsekuchen
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 text-right">
                ab 2.90 €
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-xs-12 text-center menu-close">
            <span class="icon-close"></span>
            Close
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Now for some reason should I try to add a border-bottom and padding to the `class="row-fluid"` divs these are not shown, for example I have something like this in my CSS:

```
#menuWrapper .row-fluid {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

even if I have no Div with an ID to isolate the styles the styles are not applied. It's as if the contents of the `.row-fluid` is overflowing out of the DIVs. If I want to add the border or padding on the row I have to apply it to the children divs with the styles `class="col-xs-*` Obviously I don't want to do this due to the repetition or classes. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong as I have no conflicting css (that I can isolate) that is producing this issue? Perhaps it is a lack of understanding on my part? But even if I remove all my CSS and apply the above css exclusively my view still doesn't produce the border and padding I want?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `overflow:hidden` to row-fluid

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/4qTYd/)

Css

```
#menuWrapper .row-fluid {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for convenience, you can create your own style file, it has to override properties of an existing class, or create a class with the necessary parameters

```
<div class="row-flud your klass">
         <div class="col-xs-9">
             Hausgemachter Griebenschmalz auf Schrotbrot
             <span class="grey-subtext"> Portion mit Spreewald - Gurke </ span>
         </ div>
         <div class="col-xs-3 text-right">
             3.80 €
         </ div>
     </ div>
```